# Set theory, ∈-transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The definition of ∈-transitive is where give two sets a and b, if a ∈ b, then a ⊆ b. But what are the scenarios where its not ∈-transitive or if a ∈ b then a ⊈ b?

Answer (score 1):

A simple example: $\{1\}\in\{\{1\}\}$, but $\{1\}\not\subseteq\{\{1\}\}$, since $1\notin\{\{1\}\}$. The only element of $\{\{1\}\}$ is $\{1\}$, which is not equal to $1$: $1=\{0\}$.